# I have two Java class and having @ManyToOne and I don't want to @Audit in second java class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have two Java class Product and ProductNote and I am using @Audit in Product and I don't want to @Audit on ProductNote but getting below error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An audited relation from com.test.test.domain.Product.productNotes to a not audited entity com.test.test.domain.ProductNote!

Code:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
    import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
    import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

    import com.focusrunner.ezpill.Listeners.ProductListeners;

    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;

   package com.focusrunner.ezpill.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import com.focusrunner.ezpill.Listeners.ProductListeners;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;

/**
 * Stock entry
 * 
 * @author anton
 */
@ApiModel(description = "Stock entry @author anton")
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Audited 
@EntityListeners(ProductListeners.class)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 12)
    @Column(name = "upc", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String upc;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "ndc", length = 10)
    private String ndc;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "strength", length = 255)
    private String strength;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "form", length = 255)
    private String form;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "jhi_size", length = 255)
    private String size;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "lot", length = 255)
    private String lot;

    @Column(name = "expires")
    private LocalDate expires;

    @Column(name = "price", precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "location", length = 255)
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Long quantity;

    @Size(max = 15)
    @Column(name = "status", length = 15)
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<ProductNote> productNotes = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }

    public Product upc(String upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUpc(String upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }

    public String getNdc() {
        return ndc;
    }

    public Product ndc(String ndc) {
        this.ndc = ndc;
        return this;
    }

    public void setNdc(String ndc) {
        this.ndc = ndc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Product name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public Product strength(String strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStrength(String strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public String getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public Product form(String form) {
        this.form = form;
        return this;
    }

    public void setForm(String form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public Product size(String size) {
        this.size = size;
        return this;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getLot() {
        return lot;
    }

    public Product lot(String lot) {
        this.lot = lot;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLot(String lot) {
        this.lot = lot;
    }

    public LocalDate getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }

    public Product expires(LocalDate expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
        return this;
    }

    public void setExpires(LocalDate expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public Product price(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Product location(String location) {
        this.location = location;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public Product quantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        return this;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Product status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Set<ProductNote> getProductNotes() {
        return productNotes;
    }

    public Product productNotes(Set<ProductNote> productNotes) {
        this.productNotes = productNotes;
        return this;
    }

    public Product addProductNotes(ProductNote productNote) {
        this.productNotes.add(productNote);
        productNote.setProduct(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Product removeProductNotes(ProductNote productNote) {
        this.productNotes.remove(productNote);
        productNote.setProduct(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setProductNotes(Set<ProductNote> productNotes) {
        this.productNotes = productNotes;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Product product = (Product) o;
        if (product.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), product.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", upc='" + getUpc() + "'" +
            ", ndc='" + getNdc() + "'" +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", strength='" + getStrength() + "'" +
            ", form='" + getForm() + "'" +
            ", size='" + getSize() + "'" +
            ", lot='" + getLot() + "'" +
            ", expires='" + getExpires() + "'" +
            ", price=" + getPrice() +
            ", location='" + getLocation() + "'" +
            ", quantity=" + getQuantity() +
            ", status='" + getStatus() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}


@ApiModel(description = "ProductNotes for add deleted product note @author Sumit")
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_note")
@Audited
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class ProductNote implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "note", length = 255)
    private String note;

    @Column(name = "jhi_timestamp")
    private Instant timestamp;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("productNotes")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("productNotes")
    private User user;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public ProductNote note(String note) {
        this.note = note;
        return this;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public ProductNote timestamp(Instant timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        return this;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Instant timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public ProductNote product(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
        return this;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public ProductNote user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ProductNote productNote = (ProductNote) o;
        if (productNote.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), productNote.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductNote{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", note='" + getNote() + "'" +
            ", timestamp='" + getTimestamp() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
```

I don't want to generate history and audit table for ProductNote.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: So when you fetch revisions of `Product`, is it acceptable that the collection of `ProductNote` be empty given you are not interested in auditing them?

Comment: Thanks for anwser